# How can I unbind a UDP port that has no entry in lsof?

Tags: mac, process, netstat, lsof

On my Mac, I have a UDP port that is "already in use",  but doesn't have an associated process:

```
sudo netstat -na | grep "udp.*\.500\>"
```

shows

```
udp4       0      0  192.168.50.181.500     *.*                               
udp4       0      0  192.168.29.166.500     *.*
```

`sudo lsof` doesn't show a process on port 500 (ie `sudo lsof -i:500 -P` reports nothing).

Note I'm using 'sudo' on both commands so it should show all processes.  (rebooting works, but looking for something less disruptive)

How can I unbind port 500 so I can use it again?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `sudo` to run `lsof` as root? If not, it'll only be able to see files opened by processes you own, and this is probably a system process.

Port 500 is normally used for the [isakmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Security_Association_and_Key_Management_Protocol), which is part of the IPSec suite. It'll generally show up on a Mac as a side effect of an IPSec-based VPN service.

Comment: Yes, I'm using sudo on both commands.   Yes, the actual problem is my vpn client won't start (fails with an "address already in use" error).